# Aspnet Core 1.1 Missing Windows Authentication when published

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I noticed that when publishing my new Aspnet Core 1.1 (just updated to VS 2017) project it is always missing the `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"` from the web.config.

More info and the fix I found was here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26751/publish-aspnet-core-to-iis-with-windows-authentica.html

I also tried adding:

`services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => { options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = true; });`

to my `ConfigureServices` method but it didn't help.

So my question is, is there a way to get this to work properly? Some command line argument or other way to automate it other than having to manually edit the web.config after it has been deployed?

I don't think it matters, but this is a asp.net core 1.1 targeting 4.6.2 not core.

Edit: To clarify, adding the `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"` works, the issue is its not automatically added like it is in our core 1.0 based projects. I'm wondering if there is a way to have that easily automated on generation of the web.config.

Comment: How are you hosting your application?

IIS? Kestrel through a windows service?

Comment: @DOMZE we are using IIS

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm using IIS/Kestrel on .NET Core 1.1 compiled against full framework 4.6.2 and Windows authentication without issue. First thing, I have in my project a web.config with my config that gets published with my application, so I don't have to overwrite it everytime, it is part of my project and contains quite a lot of customization useful to me, unless I missunderstood you could use that as well. Then, in my case, `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"` is good enough to be able to retrieve the windows authentication with a piece of code like that `HttpContext.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault(id => id.GetType() == typeof(WindowsIdentity));`

I think you are missing settings on the IIS level, forwardWindowsAuthToken is not enough, you also have to tell IIS that this particular web application is using windows authentication. To do so, I configure the "authentication" part of the web app, enable windows authentication, and pick the proper provider (negotiate in my case). If you just let the anonymous authentication enabled, then IIS won't ask to the client the identity of the user (using authentication protocol like negotiate and kerberos ticket) and won't transmit it to your .NET Core application.  [image]

Comment: Adding `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"` works perfectly, the issue is its not automatically added to the web.config. Once we add it, it works fine. I guess we could just include a web.config, but I like having it auto generated at deploy time, just wish it would properly include `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"` like v 1.0 did.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to have it auto-generated. I personnally use it to customize the behavior of IIS and have it in my project. I use it to define the requestTimeout, set the path of stdoutLogFile or set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT (development, staging, production ...) I don't see how an autogenerated web.config could be guessing what I need. Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think it's bad practice to have a web.config in your project, I would think the contrary, it's how it should be done.

Comment: Well before it would auto generate correctly (1.0), and I'm assuming they'll have more features and such that would be placed into the file automatically so having it auto gen is a nice feature, and why they removed it initially instead of always having one like in previous versions of asp.net. Using a web.config for now is a fine work around, but it would be nice to have a full fix for the issue.

Comment: I guess it depends your point of view and your requirement, but you could also see it the other way around: they fixed it by making it more secured not allowing some identity to be set by default. On my project for instance, by default,I prefer by far not having an identity defined unless I decide to activate the windows identity to be transmitted, which could give access to some resource if I'm not careful disregarding identities coming from windows authentication.

Comment: Sure but I'm explicitly stating I want windows auth with: `services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => { options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = true; });` so shouldn't it look at that and thus update the web.config appropriately?

Comment: Parsing your code to generate a web.config accordingly looks too complicated to me. On the contraty, one could expect that this line would overwrite the value contained in the web.config, but apparently it's not the case. Anyhow, in your case, but that's only my opinion, adding a custom web.config to the project seems like a strong solution to me, not only a workaround. Let's see if other person from SO think otherwise and can provide you with another solution.

Comment: You've seen that?  https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/104#issuecomment-303290257

Comment: It explains, directly from the MS engineering, what you have noted.

Comment: I did yeah, I wrote the original issue on github :) thanks for following up though!