# Windows Auth and jwt tokens

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I have **bearer** authentication in my asp.net core app. I need support the domain auth with **IIS**: user request `myapp.com/auth/windows`. Response is `{token: token_based_windows_loginname}`.

How to get loginname from **IIS** without windows authentication in my app?

Answer (score 1):

In your IIS web.config, you set `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"` and then you'll be able to get the authentication in your code `HttpContext.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault(id => id.GetType() == typeof(WindowsIdentity));` This way, you don't have to change your code much, IIS will take care of passing the windows authentication to your app.

Might be helpful to you:
[Aspnet Core 1.1 Missing Windows Authentication when published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057005/aspnet-core-1-1-missing-windows-authentication-when-published/44064758#44064758)